# Converting a .txt file into arff

Tags: csv, weka, arff

I have a text file(.txt) where each line has a tweet in it. Each tweet is separated by new line. I want to load the file into WEKA, but it only supports .arff as input. I intend to cluster the tweets using some clustering methods, so how do I convert the text file into arff.

Here's a screen shot of the data.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

WEKA supports CSV as well. You can convert your text file into a CSV by either code or by hand, I recommend code. Then just import it into WEKA. Once imported, and if you really want, convert it into an .arff.

Just look at how your text file is formatted. Then write a little program that parses the file and puts `,` commas to separate values. Make sure to leave the headers, WEKA will use them.

Comment: I converted the txt file into csv using excel and tried to load it but it shows `file is not recognized as a CSV Data File`

Comment: My data does not have any headers, each line is just a tweet, its a bunch of tweets in a text file

Comment: Can you post the file in its CSV format? A picture would help.

Comment: i edited the question, the screen shot is the question

Comment: That is your problem your CSV does not have any commas, so it is not really a comma separated value (CSV) file.

Comment: I loaded the text file in excel and converted it into csv and this is what i got

Comment: I am assuming you need each one of those sentences as a whole string right? Then at the end of each sentence add a comma.

Comment: But then if there is a comma in the tweet itself then that will mess up that tweet

Comment: WEKA would pick up the comma and allow you to use the file but the comma won't be in the tweet.